# How to move my main.m and app delegate class to library?

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to encapsulate my app delegate implementation. Since main is requiring app delegate import. Can I move the **main.m** also to library?

Comment: Static library does not require an entry point. You can include `main.m` function in lib but any app using your library will give error for duplicate `main()`.

Comment: I tried the same but not working as you said.

Comment: You need to ask user of your library to inherit his AppDelegate from your AppDelegate class so that all required methods get called for  your AppDelegate class. This will save you from including `main.m`

Comment: My requirement is like main.m needs to go into library.